# Override ToString() is not working in abstract class (.net-core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, .net-core, system.text.json

When interpolating objects into strings (mainly for logging purposes), it needs to be explicitly serialized  otherwise what you get is:

```
<ProjectName>.<Class>
```

or in my case

```
ConsoleApp1.Program+Person
```

So I made a very simple console application as a PoC to tackle this problem.

In this PoC I have an abstract base class that only overrides ToString method with `JsonSerializer`, so I do not need to serialize every time I want to log/ConsoleWrite my object.

```
    public abstract class BaseModel
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        }
    }
```

This abstract class is supposed to be inherited by all my models. This is the whole console app

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Person() { Name = "John", Lastname = "Doe" };
            Console.WriteLine($"Hi, {a}.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Person : BaseModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
        }
```

Running the code above ConsoleWrites

```
Hi, {}.
```

Why is it empty?

When I put a Quickwatch on `this` in the abstract method I can see that the properties are populated properly.
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: is this `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`?

Comment: Yes it is System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET Core json serializer method you used is generic, like this:

```
public static string Serialize<TValue> (TValue value,
    System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options = default);
```

By design, it only considers the properties in `TValue` when it serializes, and since you called it from your abstract class, with `this`, which of course will then be of the abstract class type, it only considers properties in the abstract class.

Basically your call is inferred to be

```
return JsonSerializer.Serialize<BaseModel>(this);
```

Fortunately, it is easy to fix, simply switch to calling the non-generic method:

```
return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, GetType());
```

Now it uses runtime information about which type you're actually calling it about instead of the abstract class, and should correctly serialize properties from your descendant type.

Answer (score 2):

Change your serialization code to (assuming you are using `System.Text.Json`):

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, this.GetType());
    }
}
```

You are using generic [`JsonSerializer.Serialize<TValue>(TValue, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize__1___0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) overload in your base class  so during compilation generic parameter `TValue` is subsitued with your `BaseModel` class, which has no properties, basically ending in `JsonSerializer.Serialize<BaseModel>(this)` call being performed.